# auto scroll not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My auto scroll with jquery does not work, here what's in my css:

```
#convo_mes{
    text-align:left;
    width:98%;
    height:80%;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #000;
    overflow-x:auto;
}
```

and in my js:

```
$(".mes").click(function(){
    var user = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#convo").html("<b>"+user+"</b>");
    $("#convo_ctrl").show();
    $(".send_to").attr("id",user);
    $(".convo_mes").html("Loading conversation <img width='15' height='15' src='./img/load.gif'>");
    setTimeout(function(){auto_scrollmes},3000);
    setTimeout(function(){get_convo(user)},2000);
});

function auto_scrollmes(){
    var objDiv = $("#convo_mes");
    objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
}
```

its still dont work, i kept changing stuff but still no luck.
here's my HTML code:

```
<div id="conversation">
<h2>Conversation</h2>
<hr />
<center>
<div id="convo">
Please select a message to load in here!
</div>
<div id="convo_mes">
<div class="convo_mes">

</div>
</div>
<div id="convo_ctrl">
<textarea spellcheck="false" placeholder="Enter your message here..."                                     id='mes_text_area'></textarea><a href="#send" id="send_message">Send</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){auto_scrollmes()},3000);` you must call function

Comment: didnt work even though i added ()

Comment: make jsfiddle - it will help :) https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I guess no one can answer

Comment: Yes we can answer but it will be easier for us if you provide the HTML code as well :)

Answer (score 0):

whats is not working in your code

```js
$(".mes").click(function(){
    var user = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#convo").html("<b>"+user+"</b>");
    $("#convo_ctrl").show();
    $(".send_to").attr("id",user);
    $(".convo_mes").html("Loading conversation <img width='15' height='15' src='./img/load.gif'>");
    setTimeout(function(){auto_scrollmes},3000);
    setTimeout(function(){get_convo(user)},2000);
});

function auto_scrollmes(){
    var objDiv = $("#convo_mes");
    objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
}
```

```css
#convo_mes{
    text-align:left;
    width:98%;
    height:80%;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #000;
    overflow-x:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="conversation">
<h2>Conversation</h2>
<hr />
<center>
<div id="convo">
Please select a message to load in here!
</div>
<div id="convo_mes">
<div class="convo_mes">

</div>
</div>
<div id="convo_ctrl">
<textarea spellcheck="false" placeholder="Enter your message here..." id='mes_text_area'></textarea><a href="#send" id="send_message">Send</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the function auto_scrollmes does not run after 3 seconds. But i placed it on the js. and I set it to run every 1 millisecond, like this setInterval(auto_scrollmes,100); i lloked at the console and there was no error still does not auto scroll.